# How to delete an android contact using C# Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.android

I've been trying to get my app to delete contacts from the an android phone using C# and Xamarin Forms. I would like to be able to search for a contact by the contact's display name and then delete it from the contacts.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

I have now been able to delete all contacts from the phone in one go, but I still want to be able to delete selected contacts using the display name to identify the contact. This is my code, what changes would I have to make to be able delete selected contacts?

```
List<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new List<ContentProviderOperation>();

ops.Add(ContentProviderOperation.NewDelete(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ContentUri).Build());

Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver.ApplyBatch(ContactsContract.Authority, ops);
```

Comment: You need to use [DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/) to implement this feature in native Android.

Comment: I've got a Dependency Service for  adding and getting contacts from the phone, but I can't work out how to delete selected contacts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of work on it this is my solution. ToDelete is the string I have passed in the compare to the display name of the contact.

```
Context thisContext = Android.App.Application.Context;

            string[] Projection = new string[] { ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.LookupKey, ContactsColumns.DisplayName };

            ICursor cursor = thisContext.ContentResolver.Query(ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentUri, Projection, null, null, null);

            while (cursor != null & cursor.MoveToNext())
            {
                string lookupKey = cursor.GetString(0);
                string name = cursor.GetString(1);

                if (name == ToDelete)
                {
                    var uri = Uri.WithAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentLookupUri, lookupKey);
                    thisContext.ContentResolver.Delete(uri, null, null);
                    cursor.Close();
                    return;
                }
            }
```